# Simple window size in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, web, screen

I am using JQM with HTML5 boiler plate.  My objective (for tests purposes) is to have in a desktop browser, an overall div that will show me the expected size areas of my app on a real device.  In a desktop browser, however, the width compared to the iphone4 browser width layout do not seems to match.  I do not wish to change the viewport meta definition, although I suspect that it is my problem.  Can somebody explain to me:

Why the size of a div of size 640 x 960 px (with a border of 1 px and a position of absolute) does not reflect the same size area appearance on the actual device with this type of setup ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Chrome's Developer Tools. You can choose to spoof your User Agent as well as the device metrics for different devices.

When in Chrome:

1. Press F12.
2. Click on the gear icon to the bottom right (settings).
3. Click on the Overrides tab.
4. Here you can choose to change your User Agent string or override the viewport of your browser to match specific devices (like the iPhone). If you change the User Agent string to mimic an iPhone then the Device Metrics should auto adjust to be the proper size for the same device.

Note that you must keep the Chrome Developer Tools open, as soon as you close them you lose the UA spoofing and Device Metrics spoofing as well.

To directly answer your question, different screens have different pixel densities, so a screen with higher pixel density will show the same number of pixels in a smaller physical area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was clear.  I also found that, even with 640x960 resolution for an iphone4, your referring settings must be set to 320x480 for the devices metrics.  My objective is met, I still do not understand, though, this asymmetry between screen resolution and pixel density.  I get it that the screen size as an impact, but I still don't get it how?  For instance, why I needed to enter 320x480 for the iphone4 when the resolution is higher?  If you have time, can you write a small comment on this ?  Anyway, I consider this a valid answer.

Comment: @Alain I can't think of a succinct explanation however if you search Google you'll find a lot of good information, this article for instance: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html. I searched the term: `css dpi`.

Comment: Thanks I added a comment, I thing it helped me, Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on,

When dealing with CSS Media queries there is a difference between the

- `device-width` and the
- `width`.

For the iphone4, for instance, although the resolution

- (`width` x `height`) is equal to (640 x 960),

the device is actually presenting

- (`device-width` x `device-height`) as equal to (320 x 480)

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density) we observe that **each CSS pixel is handled by 2 screen resolution pixel**.  This is the consequence of the 2 different size.

This help: [Pixel density for different devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density)